# Convert enum to string with impl fmt::Display

Tags: rust, enums

Using Rust, I am trying to create an error code enum.

```rust
pub enum ErrorCode {
    InvalidUsername,
    InvalidPassword,
}
```

I want this enum to be used in a JSON response using actix_web, so I need to convert the enum to a string.

To do this, I tried to implement `fmt::Display` on the `ErrorCode` enum:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum ErrorCode {
    InvalidUsername,
    InvalidPassword,
}

impl fmt::Display for ErrorCode {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", *self)
     }
}
```

But the program crashes with an infinite loop whenever I try to run `.to_string()` on `ErrorCode`.

```
thread 'actix-rt:worker:0' has overflowed its stack
fatal runtime error: stack overflow
[1]    85991 abort      ./target/debug/app
```

I would like to have the enum as a string, and be able to mutate the string in the `impl fmt::Display` so I can do things such as convert it to snake_case.

Comment: You might be looking for something like [strum](https://crates.io/crates/strum), which introduces procedural macros which you can use to [derive the Display trait](https://docs.rs/strum_macros/0.20.1/strum_macros/derive.Display.html) (among others) for an enum with [many customization options](https://docs.rs/strum/0.20.0/strum/additional_attributes/index.html). You can also choose to implement `Display` yourself by modifying and returning the output of another method implemented by a strum macro, like [AsRefStr](https://docs.rs/strum_macros/0.20.1/strum_macros/derive.AsRefStr.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `write!()` inside the `fmt()` function to substitute {} with `self`, as this macro calls exact same function, thus creating the infinite loop.

Instead, you should use the parameter of the function `f: &mut fmt::Formatter` to write the result you want.

```
match self {
  ErrorCode::InvalidUsername => f.write_str("Invalid user name"),
  ...
}
```

There are also libraries that help you to reduce the boilerplate code in this case. One is [strum](https://crates.io/crates/strum) as [EvilTak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4038191/eviltak) suggested.

Comment: Thank you and @EvilTak, I ended up going with strum and it worked perfectly.

Comment: You can absolutely call `write!` inside the `fmt` function. [The official documentation does that in its example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html). The issue here is that it's invoking `Display` on `self` *which is what's being implemented*. It's crashing because the Display implementation just recurses on itself without ever doing anything useful. [Delegating to `Debug` works just fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ddeeef715b44f69aab1ec7b0fb40ce92).